# TypeError when searching google with the google api python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests, urllib, json

def search(search_string):
  query = urllib.parse.urlencode({'q': search_string})
  url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
  search_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  search_results = search_response.read().decode("utf8")
  results = json.loads(search_results)
  data = results['responseData']
  print('Total results: %s' % data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
  hits = data['results']
  print('Top %d hits:' % len(hits))
  for h in hits: print(' ', h['url'])
  print('For more results, see %s' % data['cursor']['moreResultsUrl'])
  print(hits)

search(input('Enter search query:'))
```

I used this code that I found on this site, when I enter something to search it returns this error:

```
print('Total results: %s' % data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

...and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

This message means that you are trying to access a key of a `None` value, something like `None['key']`.

This means that either `data` or `data['cursor']` are empty. You should debug these to see what are their values. Maybe `data` is empty because there was an error on your request.